# Reopen Request (What good are psychics...)

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question:  [What good are psychics who control the strong or weak forces?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/40122/what-good-are-psychics-who-control-the-strong-or-weak-forces?rq=1)

Has been closed as "not clear what you're asking".  OP subsequently edited the question; it seems like a pretty good worldbuilding question now.  Basically, "given that powers X and Y are in the world, how could folks use it"?

I'm suggesting that this question is now clear enough to reopen.  Thoughts?

Comment: If a question is edited after being put on hold, it is automatically added to the reopen review queue. If enough people agree to reopen it, it will be reopened. Creating a post for each one is, generally, unnecessary.

Comment: @Frostfyre people will see it in the review queue, but it's also fine to bring specific questions to the community's attention on meta or in chat.  I sometimes do that if there's been a major edit or the user is new and has fixed the problems, in the interest of getting it reopened more quickly.

Comment: @Frostfyre For completeness: Only if the question is still "on hold". Questions that have transitioned to "closed" are not automatically entered into the reopen review queue, but they are entered into the queue if one user votes to reopen.

Comment: I still don’t get it, and certain wording makes me suspect POB or too broad if I did understand it.

Comment: I think it's good that you raised this on Meta. We don't get reopen requests often enough. That's also why I upvoted this meta discussion, even if I am against reopening the question in its current form, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### I would vote *primarily opinion-based* in its current form

The edits from the OP were pretty superficial. After the closure of the question he made some text italic, some text bold and added the following sentences:

> [...], in fact in fact pretty much any use of these forces on the macroscopic scale has the same problems[.]

and

> So what exactly could someone do with one of these powers? Applications that would be actually be likely to come up in a rpg or story are more preferable than extremely niche uses.

Note that the second one looks like he added a question that was not there before to try and clear it up, but there already was another paragraph that started like

> So what is a weak-force, or strong-force psychic to do?

So there is not really a notable difference in my eyes. There are some additional criteria though that weren't there when the question was put on hold, but nothing that clarifies the premise - and the criteria are just that something would be able to come up in a story or RPG, which is not really a good way to quantify answers. There are a lot of stories and RPG's with a lot of different genres out there.

**But: questions that are supposed to be reviewed should be reviewed as a whole based on the current guidelines**, so here is what I think about the question as it reads now: I would vote for *primarily opinion based*.

There are still some aspects that look like the author created a world and is expecting everyone to be familiar with the concepts. For example:

> Their powers fall into groups that control different well defined things, with many controlling fundamental forces.

What *well defined things* does the OP mean here? He later states something about *kinetic energy* and *electromagnetic control*. I am not too sure about whether he is not mixing up a few concepts here. For example I know *psions* in fiction to be some sort of mages, people with special powers so that they can control their surroundings through a power that stems from their minds. Powers such as telekinesis. Is that a *well defined thing* for the OP?

But anyway, the text reads as if some superhero could control the strong force or the weak force and the questions make it pretty clear that everything else is out-of-scope for the question so I can safely ignore it even if I don't fully understand what the OP means. I can think about the part of

> So what exactly could someone do with one of these powers?

The OP is asking us for story-elements because he had this [High Concept](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions) of people being able to control fundamental forces but he doesn't know what the implications are. And now he is looking for a list of useful things to do with this invented power.

We had a similar question some time later: [What would powers based on the four fundamental forces look like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/67996/what-would-powers-based-on-the-four-fundamental-forces-look-like)

While there were a few comments I think [the first](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/67996/what-would-powers-based-on-the-four-fundamental-forces-look-like#comment196605_67996) one is the one that explains best what is wrong with both of these questions in my eyes:

> the extent and limits of their abilities are up to you not us, you might want to refine your question. determining to what extent they can manipulate them would be a good start

The OP to the second question also says:

> I'm interested in what the manipulators of those forces can do, and what they cannot, and if they doing it would look cool to potential observers or it would just be imperceptible.

We don't know what is *cool* for the OP. I like playing DnD and I think there are some pretty cool concepts in that game - go ask people on the street whether DnD is cool...

The same with the OP of the question this meta discussion is about - what stories and RPG's does the OP mean? There are a lot of different genres and the OP might not like the same stuff that I read/play...

Coming up with the extent of powers is something that should be defined by the OP, not by the answerers. Asking what to do with a power that you don't define could be anything - and only you can define whether an answer sounds good for you. Every answer would be equally valid and everyone can come up with an answer. These points apply to the question that this Meta post is about as well as the other one I linked.

This is a brainstorming request for the results of a high concept the OP came up with, which makes this an opinion-based question.